# node-webkit: calls to require() throw "AssertionError: missing path"

Tags: node.js, webkit, node-webkit, assertions

I'm writing a node-webkit application (based on [node-webkit-hipster-seed](https://github.com/Anonyfox/node-webkit-hipster-seed)) and I'm trying to import additional node modules. I've found that even if I attempt to import default node modules (such as `fs` and `http`) I get the following error:

```
var http = require('http');
AssertionError: missing path
```

with the stack trace:

```
"AssertionError: missing path
at Module.require (module.js:359:3)
at require (module.js:376:17)
at window.require (eval at undefined, <anonymous>:1:112)
at _require (file:///Users/...project/_public/js/vendor.js:92:38)
at require (file:///Users/...project/_public/js/vendor.js:162:16)
at eval (eval at undefined, <anonymous>:2:6)
at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (eval at undefined, <anonymous>:603:39)
at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (eval at undefined, <anonymous>:562:52)
at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (eval at undefined, <anonymous>:481:21)"
```

I'm not sure what's going on. Is something mangling `require` that I don't know about? Is this `require` not the CommonJS require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was that I also had [ace.js](http://ace.c9.io/) loaded, which also assigns a global `require` function.

To solve this, you can add the following code snippet: ([source](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/faq-name-conflict))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.requireNode = window.require;
    window.require = undefined; 
</script>
```

in the `head` of your main html file. Then just use `requireNode` instead of `require`.

Answer (score 0):

**The Exception is:**

```
AssertionError: missing path
     at Module.require (module.js:351:3)
     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\learning\index.js:1:77)
     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
     at Function._load (C:\Users\12885\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\pmx\lib\transaction.js:62:21)
learning-0 (err):     at C:\Users\12885\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainer.js:217:23
learning-0 (err):     at C:\Users\12885\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
```

**The solution is:**

```
var express = require(express); ---> var express = require('express');
```